# Have I got this right, Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

So just if I got it right.. is it right that Mobile devices only uses
HVGA and QVGA?
And the sizes between....

So i could use the following markup:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml
```

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp - (HVGA, 320x480)
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp - (QVGA, 240x320)

And from this have different drawable folders.... 
Or Im I thinking wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check [New Tools For Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) where it given the full details

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the following link and you will get all the required information about the screen sizes for android development :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html open this link will get all required information for screen support and layout

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices only uses HVGA and QVGA? **Incorrect**. New phones use much larger resolution.

Comment: What sizes then? HVGA, QVGA and WVGA?